# Visual Basic Datagridview to mysql with primary key(auto generated number in sequence)

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am developing a program that imports excel into datagridview and datagridview into the mysql database. my datagridview doesnt have a auto generated primary key.
i want to know how to insert the content of datagridview into the mysql table with a primary key that will generate sequential number whenever a new row is added.
my code looks like this

the "idno" is the primary key and i want it to generate a sequential number whenever i enter a new row

---

```
Private Sub ImportDataButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ImportDataButton.Click
    Try
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
        connection.Open()
        For i As Integer = 0 To DGV1.Rows.Count - 1 Step +1
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("insert into table_import values(@no,@web,@channel,@facebook,@description)", connection)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@no", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@web", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@channel", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@facebook", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@idno", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value =
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


        Next
        connection.Close()
        MsgBox("Data successfully imported !")
        viewDGV1()
```

Comment: What do you not understand about the information you found when you searched the web for "mysql auto generate id" or the like?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table is configured with an autonumber primary key column. Then immediately after the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` you should do another bit of SQL:

```
cmd.commandtext = "select last_insert_id()"
myid = cmd.ExecuteScalar
```

And myid will contain the value of the primary key for the last inserted column.